# PAYPAL: How to charge users for a 1 year account and after checkout, send user to login?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a PHP website, in which people sign up for 1 year, manually per year, with no recurring fees. But, I'm new to Paypal. I've made a business paypal account. And when I make a button, and paste to my page, I just don't know what to do next.

What I want is for someone to pay with credit/debit card. And after they submit, it redirects to my 
post.php process page. In the process page, it will check whether the user actually paid in the last page, or just typed the page in the URL to get a free account. If he paid, add the user to database. but if he just typed the URL, boot him.

My goal is:
**Signup.php---> Paypal (via paypal button)--------> post.php (validate whether is paid)-----> (if true, go to login.php)--->login.php**

Im very familiar with PHP so any snippets or examples would mean so much. And if you don't mind, some thourough explanations would be highly appreciated. It's just that their documentation is a total mess (to paypal noobs anyway). Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks so much

Comment: That's quite the project to just "jump into" for a newbie. Lordy, I remember when typing `del.` was a real killer.

Comment: I'm familiar with several languages, so any examples would be understood